# how to display relation data into json format from two table in yii2 restful api

Tags: php, json, rest, yii2, relation

I got the problem to display the data from two table into JSON format and working on yii2 restful api.

this is my **structure database:**

```
TABLE `volunteer`(
`volunteer_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`state_id` int(11) null 

TABLE `state`(
`state_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`state` varchar(225) null
```

**volunteerController.php**

```
public $modelClass = 'app\models\Volunteer';
public function behaviors()
{
    return ArrayHelper::merge(parent::behaviors(),[
        'verbs' => [
            'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
            'actions' => [
                'delete' => ['post'],
            ],
        ],
    ]);
}
```

**config/web.php**

```
'rules' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\rest\UrlRule', 'controller' => ['volunteer','state','post']],
],
'request' => [
        // !!! insert a secret key in the following (if it is empty) - this is required by cookie validation
        'cookieValidationKey' => 'QMoK0GQoN7_VViTXxPdTISiOrITBI4Gy',
                    'parsers' => [
                    'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
                    ],

    ],
```

this is the result in JSON format:

```
[
  {
    "volunteer_id": 1,
    "country_id": 1,
    "state_id": 12,
  }
]
```

so that result is not what I want. What I want is state_id should return state data from table state which means **state : New York** . Not return  the state_id. How to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done with overriding `fields()` like that:

```
public function fields()
{
    return [
        'volunteer_id',
        'country_id',
        'state' => function ($model) {
            return $model->state->name; // Return related model property, correct according to your structure
        },
    ];
}
```

Additionally you can eagerly load this relation in `prepareDataProvider()` method using `with()`.

**Official docs:**

- [Overriding fields()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-resources.html#overriding-fields)
- [Customizing actions](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-controllers.html#customizing-actions)

Comment: i dont understand 
'state' => function ($model) {
            return $model->state->name; // Return related model property, correct according to your structure
        },
where to put this code actually ?

Comment: Did you read the docs by the link I provided? It should be done in your ActiveRecord model.

Comment: ok .. i got it . I replace return $model->states->state and its working 100%. thanks for your regard.

Comment: I not use the docs you provided. I just create another function public function getStates()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(State::className(),['state_id'=>'state_id']);
    }

Comment: THis problem already solved and thanks because your solution solve my problem. but I got another problem . You can look from this site [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30410577/yii2-restful-api-display-the-data-from-database-into-json-format-with-specific)

Comment: in prepareDataProvider() method using with() doesn't show related data

Answer (score 0):

```
public function fields(){
    return [
        'volunteer_id',
        'country_id',
        'state' => function ($model) {
            return $model->setOtherAttr($model->state_id); 
        },
        'other_attr1',
        'other_attr2',
    ];
}
public function setOtherAttr($state_id){
    $state = State::find()->where(['state_id'=>$state_id])->one();
    $this->other_attr1 = $state->other_attr1;
    $this->other_attr2 = $state->other_attr2;
    return $state->state;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following code:

```
public function setOtherAttr($state_id){
  if (($model = State::find()->where(['state_id'=>$state_id])->all()) !== null) {
    return $model;
  } else {
   return '';
  }
}
```