# Yii2 Restful API : display the data from database into JSON format with specific condition SQL

Tags: json, api, rest, yii2

I'm working on Yii2 restful API and want to display the data into JSON format. This is my **structure database**:

```
TABLE `volunteer`(
`volunteer_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`state_id` int(11) null
`nama` varchar(200) null

TABLE `state`(
`state_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`state` varchar(225) null
```

Basically, when I run at browser with specific ID = 1 (http://localhost/KDMA/web/index.php/volunteers/1) the data will display like this:

```
{
   "volunteer_id": "1",
   "state_id":"12",
   "nama": "Bentong",
}
```

that result is display the data from volunteer_id = 1. **So, what I want to do right now is display the data from state_id, not volunteer_id**. For example in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM volunteer where state_id = 12;
```

What are the ways that can solve my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question I think you can solve the problem as follows:
try adding another method in the controller that performs the action you need eg in volunteerController

```
public function actionViewByState ($ id)
   {

     if (($ model = State :: findOne ($ id))! == null) {
         $ this-> setHeader (200);
     echo json_encode (array ('status' => 1, 'date' => array_filter ($ model-> attributes)), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
     } Else {

       $ this-> setHeader (400);
       echo json_encode (array ('status' => 0, 'error_code' => 400, 'message' => 'Bad request'), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
       exit;
     }
   }
```

and then call the action with

```
  http: //localhost/KDMA/web/index.php/volunteers/view-by-state/1
```

Comment: thanks because take your time to help me solve this problem. Btw, this problem already solved based on logic you give to me and I combine with my friend logic. In my volunteerController.php I just put this function 
public $modelClass = 'app\models\Volunteer';
    //public $modelC= 'app\models\State';

    public function actions()
    {
        $actions = parent::actions();
        unset($actions['index'], $actions['view']);
        return $actions;
    }
and some raw sql at function view and index. Thank you so much

Comment: If you think my  answer is useful please rate it or accept it